SSL2 mkII audio interface output and monitor noise
beginner here. I've tried to setup SSL2 mkII audio interface with a pair of condenser microphones for piano with SSL2's asio drivers on windows, using reaper (and tried ableton live) daw.
I can record appropriately and rendering the recording sounds clean, but both the monitors and outputs severely distort the sound where I can barely hear the music among the static noise. The noise stops when I pause the recording.
I'm not sure where to look in terms of troubleshooting and what might be the issue. Searching on the internet has not shown up anything either. Would appreciate pointers.
What I hear from the monitors/outputs: https://file.io/ASeuDpp5km8V
Edit: ignoring the DAW's output, the audio interface's monitors sound clean. It's only the output/monitor from DAW that's noisy.

What monitors? What cable from soundcard to Monitors?  Most typical problem is incorrect type of cable.

Monitors are studio headphones connected with 3/4" jack to headphone slots. SSL2 is connected to PC directly via USB. I've noticed that if I just use the interface for monitoring and ignore the PC output, the sound is clean, it's only the monitor/output coming from PC that's so noisy.

Your link to the audio sample doesn't work anymore. Can you re-upload it?

I will write this as an answer, although I cannot say I am sure.
But as usual with faults we do elimination.

The recording works because you have rendered the signal out and that sounds OK. Otherwise a common problem is setting gain too high resulting in distortion (not in this case though).

The output of the unit works because you have tried sending other sounds out to it and it works.

But the output from the DAW does not work. This points to there beeing something fishy going on with that part.


This makes me guess that there is something amiss in the connection between the DAW and the sound card. One of the components in between is the special ASIO driver supplied by SSL. Installing it correctly has a full web page description in the manual suggestion to me that it is possible to get it wrong.
My suggestion than is to first download and reinstall the ASIO driver and carefully follow the instructions on how to set it up. In my mind this seems to be the most probable cause for the problem.
